# CSS Button with right arrow

Tags: html, css, button

Easiest way to make this button?

[image]

So far I have this, basically need the right arrow.

```css
.end-btn {
  margin-top: 2vw;
  background-color: #DAA521;
  border: none;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 3vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="end-btn"> View profile </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com). Using the free version you can use the following code, to do it.

```
<button>View Profile <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

You just need an email address to start.
https://fontawesome.com/start

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way to give right arrow to the button.

```css
.end-btn {
  margin-top: 2vw;
  background-color: #DAA521;
  border: none;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 3vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="end-btn"> View profile &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;> </button>
```

Also you can use some icons if you can add external css to your html like below.

```css
.end-btn {
  margin-top: 2vw;
  background-color: #DAA521;
  border: none;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 7vw;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.end-btn i {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button class="end-btn"> View profile <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.c-btn{
  border: none;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 12px 48px 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='7.41' height='12' viewBox='0 0 7.41 12'%3E%3Cpath d='M10,6,8.59,7.41,13.17,12,8.59,16.59,10,18l6-6Z' transform='translate(-8.59 -6)' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 24px center;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-btn">View Profile</button>
```